# Kernel Panic unlocking an unlocked mutex or spinlock on MacBook 2008

Tags: macbook-pro, crash, performance, kernel-panic

My MacBook 2008 froze and I had to press the power button. What does all this mean? This is the report I got back:

```
Interval Since Last Panic Report:  1640806 sec
Panics Since Last Report:          1
Anonymous UUID:                    3768E8C9-9757-4421-BA90-5D7E95694567

Fri Oct 17 13:20:50 2014
panic(cpu 1 caller 0x226ec0): "thread_invoke: preemption_level -1, possible cause: unlocking an unlocked mutex or spinlock"@/SourceCache/xnu/xnu-1504.15.3/osfmk/kern/sched_prim.c:1471
Backtrace (CPU 1), Frame : Return Address (4 potential args on stack)
0x5d203e28 : 0x21b837 (0x5dd7fc 0x5d203e5c 0x223ce1 0x0) 
0x5d203e78 : 0x226ec0 (0x593ab8 0xffffffff 0x593a50 0x226790) 
0x5d203ef8 : 0x2275c6 (0x83f8b98 0xc8c4 0x1 0x0) 
0x5d203f68 : 0x219484 (0x2a1765 0x0 0x1 0x4f811e) 
0x5d203fa8 : 0x2aacb4 (0xffffffff 0x1 0x5d203fc8 0x9240524) 
0x5d203fc8 : 0x2a1976 (0x0 0x0 0x10 0x9240524) 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: Safari Webpage P

Mac OS version:
10K549

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:33:36 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_I386
System model name: MacBook4,1 (Mac-F22788A9)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 220744999422441
unloaded kexts:
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireSBP2  4.0.6 (addr 0x74007000, size 0x69632) - last unloaded 208079346818347
loaded kexts:
net.kromtech.kext.Firewall  2.3.6 - last loaded 207982800254397
com.cisco.nke.ipsec 2.0.1
com.parallels.kext.prl_vnic 6.0 12092.670880
com.parallels.kext.prl_netbridge    6.0 12092.670880
com.parallels.kext.prl_usb_connect  6.0 12092.670880
com.parallels.kext.prl_hid_hook 6.0 12092.670880
com.parallels.kext.prl_hypervisor   6.0 12092.670880
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.0.5f14
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.3d0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.57
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelPenrynProfile    17
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    4.7.0a1
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.0.46
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.1d2
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    2.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.7
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.0.20
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelGMAX3100 6.3.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelGMAX3100FB   6.3.6
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AudioIPCDriver 1.1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTrackpad   201.6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyEventDriver   201.6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 201.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  303.8
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  2.6.8
com.apple.BootCache 31.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.7.3
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  1.6.4
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   160.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  2.1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelPIIXATA  2.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    4.2.4
com.apple.iokit.AppleYukon2 3.2.1b1
com.apple.driver.AirPortBrcm43224   428.42.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   4.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBUHCI   4.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  1.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   1.3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   1.3.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    1.3.6
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 142.6.0
com.apple.security.sandbox  1
com.apple.security.quarantine   0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   2.1.14
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   142.6.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.0.5f14
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileReadCounterAction  17
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileTimestampAction    10
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileThreadInfoAction   14
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileRegisterStateAction    10
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileKEventAction   10
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileCallstackAction    20
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 4.7.0a1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.0.3
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.0.5f14
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.0.5f14
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   74.2
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    2.4.5f3
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.3
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.0d5
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.8.3fc2
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.3
com.apple.iokit.AppleProfileFamily  41
com.apple.driver.CSRUSBBluetoothHCIController   2.4.5f3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBBluetoothHCIController 2.4.5f3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   2.4.5f3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   4.2.4
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  4.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  2.6.8
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.6
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.6
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  3.9.0
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 402.1
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.2.6
com.apple.iokit.IOATAPIProtocolTransport    2.5.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   2.6.8
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.0.6
com.apple.iokit.IOATAFamily 2.5.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 4.2.4
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   320.1
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  1.10
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 4.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    1.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 1.6.6
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  6
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 289.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.6.3
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  1.3.6
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.6.5
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.3.0
Model: MacBook4,1, BootROM MB41.00C1.B00, 2 processors, Intel Core 2 Duo, 2.4 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.31f1
Graphics: Intel GMA X3100, GMA X3100, Built-In, 144 MB
Memory Module: global_name
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x88), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.10.131.42.4)
Bluetooth: Version 2.4.5f3, 2 service, 12 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: AirPort, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: FUJITSU MHY2250BH, 232.89 GB
Parallel ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-867
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8205, 0x1a100000 / 2
USB Device: Built-in iSight, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8501, 0xfd400000 / 2
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x0229, 0x5d200000 / 3
USB Device: IR Receiver, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8242, 0x5d100000 / 2
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be resolved by upgrading to Mavericks or Yosemite via the Mac App Store.